# Bash "cd" command not working properly

Tags: git, bash, function

I'm doing a function, to have in my bash profile, that clones a git repository, enters in the created directory and (optionally) checkout to the provided brach.

The Code is:

```
# Clone repository from git, enter in it end checkout to provided branch (default master)
function clone_with_branch () {
    g clone $1
    cd "$1" | cut -f 2 -d '/' | cut -f 1 -d '.' 
    if [ "$2" != "null" ]; then
        g co  "$2"
    fi
}
```

But, lets say i write this in the command line:

```
clone_with_branch git@github.com:somepage/someproject.git
```

It gives me the message:

```
bash: cd: git@github.com:somepage/someproject.git: No such file or directory
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

P.S: If you switch the cd command with echo (for testing), it will print the right dir to you...

Comment: It's *very unlikely* `cd` is "not working properly".  Start by wondering what you might be doing wrong, not what a decades old tool used by thousands of people every day might be doing wrong.

Comment: `cd` works correctly. It is being used incorrectly. Read the nice error message reported. `bash: cd: >>git@github.com:<<somepage/someproject.git: No such file or directory`. It seems to be telling the truth.

Comment: Man relax, it's just a way of saying that I could not get this to work... Neither think of a better title..for me it's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to cd into $1 and then passing the results of that to cut.  You want to cd to the *result* of the cut:

```
cd `echo "$1" | cut -f 2 -d '/' | cut -f 1 -d '.'`
```

(Notice the backticks)

Comment: `$(...)` is much easier to notice than a pair of backticks.

Comment: I managed to do it, was this exactly way. I was going to put this here but you already did it. Thanks man!

Comment: I'd prefer using `basename` for this, e.g. `cd $(basename "$1" .git)`; it's shorter and describes the operation.